# Is it possible to limit the amount of variations a user can do with woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A lot of the Q&A I'm finding online is about increasing the amount of variations you can make on a woocommerce variable product but I'm trying to limit the amount to 30. The reason being on some client sites I have done, they have like over 1000 variations which makes the product take an age to load. I'm creating a multivendor site so I'm trying to prevent problematic products from the get go. Some of the functions I have tried are:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'ww_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );

function ww_ajax_variation_threshold( $default, $product ) {
    return 30;
}
```

and also

```
function wpse_rest_batch_items_limit( $limit ) {
    $limit = 30;

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_batch_items_limit', 'wpse_rest_batch_items_limit' );
```

These don't seem to work for me unfortunately. I also want to try and replicate this in the variation popup message. (*see below*)

[image]

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a limit for "per add" in admin area, add `define(WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS,30)` constant in `wp-config.php` and the popup you mentioned will show this number automatically. But consider that its just a interface limit for creating at time, and  will NOT limit total variations user can build on product.

Comment: Ok this worked for the popup so that much is great thanks. Its just a shame I can't seem to prevent users adding more than 30.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [cut-off at 30 variations](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-variations-breaking-after-30-variations/).

Only from this number on AJAX takes over loading the data.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'ww_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );

function ww_ajax_variation_threshold( $default, $product ) {
    return 31; //     > 30
}
```